# Created Subdomain in cloudflare, added new website hosted on IIS returns HTTP 404 error

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, cloudflare

I have hosting with on IP 111.11.111.11 and added multiple DNS records in the Cloudflare with type A using the same IP.
Following the type of DNS records I have

1. sub1.domain.com
2. sub2.domain.com
3. domain.com
4. www

Then I have added multiple websites in IIS. But when I hit on the browser it gives a 404 error.
https://prnt.sc/1hm0k7o

Am I missing something in the configuration on IIS or Cloudflare?

Comment: If you don't have the correct site bindings, then 404 is expected. https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: Could you please share screenshots of your bindings and how did you configure the DNS ?